# Flutter, How to seamlessly scroll the view when keyboard opened

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

[image]

This is the best example I found over Google, imagine if this form also have login button on bottom and as user taps in last TextField it should nicely translate the UI to upword. How can I achieve something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there are two things that you can do.
Despite there are no code snippets for me to look at:

1.) I think you might consider wrapping the body of your screen with the *SingleChildScrollView()* widget.

2.) Or maybe you can wrap the TextFields with the *ListTile()* widget.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for answer, singlechildscrollview make the page content scrollable not the adjust accordingly to keyboard if it's opened or nkt, not sure about listTile